# Issue while navigating to new activity when using async task

Tags: java, android

Can anyone please tell me how to login? I am trying to login in with the user name `Priyanka` and password `Priyanka` but it is unsuccessful.

Can anyone help me out?

```
package org.example.rig_parking;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class Rig_ParkingActivity extends Activity {

String username,password;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    

        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/semibold.ttf");
        TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rig_parkmain);
        myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        TextView forget_main = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.forget_main);
        forget_main.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        final EditText email_main = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_main);
        email_main.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        final EditText password_main = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_main);
        password_main.setTypeface(myTypeface);
    
        Button copy=(Button) findViewById(R.id.copyright);
        copy.setText("(c)Rig Parking 2010-2012,All Rights Reserved");
        copy.setTypeface(myTypeface);
    
        TextView register=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_main);       
     register.setTypeface(myTypeface);
   
        register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        
     Intent register=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Register.class);    
     startActivity(register);               
        }
    });
    
 /*      forget_main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        
     Intent register=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Tab.class); 
     startActivity(register);               
        }
    });
        */
        TextView login=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_main);       
        login.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        
            username=email_main.getText().toString();
            password=password_main.getText().toString();
            
            if(username.equals("")&&password.equals(""))
            {
                final AlertDialog alertDialog51;                    
                  alertDialog51 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Rig_ParkingActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog51.setMessage(Html
                       .fromHtml("<font color='#00beb4'><b> Enter Email and Password</b></font>"));                                                                                                     
                    alertDialog51.setButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {                            
                        alertDialog51.dismiss();    
                               }
                         });            
                    alertDialog51.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        alertDialog51.dismiss();                                                
                       }
                    });                         
                    alertDialog51.show();                           
            }                                   
            else if(username.equals(""))
             {
                final AlertDialog alertDialog51;                    
                  alertDialog51 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Rig_ParkingActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog51.setMessage(Html
                       .fromHtml("<font color='#00beb4'><b>    Enter Email    </b></font>"));                                                                                                       
                    alertDialog51.setButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {                            
                        alertDialog51.dismiss();    
                               }
                         });            
                    alertDialog51.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        alertDialog51.dismiss();                                                
                       }
                    });                         
                    alertDialog51.show(); 
             }
            else if(password.equals(""))
             {
                final AlertDialog alertDialog51;                    
                  alertDialog51 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Rig_ParkingActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog51.setMessage(Html
                       .fromHtml("<font color='#00beb4'><b>    Enter  Password   </b></font>"));                                                                                                        
                    alertDialog51.setButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {                            
                        alertDialog51.dismiss();    
                               }
                         });            
                    alertDialog51.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        alertDialog51.dismiss();                                                
                       }
                    });                         
                    alertDialog51.show(); 
             }
            else{
            LoginTask logintsk=new LoginTask();
            logintsk.execute();             
            }
            
        }
    });
    
    }
    private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 
 
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Rig_ParkingActivity.this);
    
        @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { 

            this.dialog.setMessage("Loading ..."); 
            this.dialog.show(); 
        } 

    
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... unused) { 
        
      Log.i("Priyanka", "username"+username);
      Log.i("Priyanka", "password"+password);
      String auth=BusinessLogic_login.candidatelogin(username, password); 
      String userid=auth; 
        Log.i("priyanka", "auth"+auth);
        if(auth.equals("0")||(auth.equals("")))
        {
            Rig_ParkingActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {             
                public void run() {                 
                    final AlertDialog alertDialog51;                    
                  alertDialog51 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Rig_ParkingActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog51.setMessage(Html
                       .fromHtml("<font color='#00beb4'><b>Enter correct Email or Password</b></font>"));                                                                                                       
                    alertDialog51.setButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {                            
                        alertDialog51.dismiss();    
                               }
                         });            
                    alertDialog51.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        alertDialog51.dismiss();                                                
                       }
                    });                         
                    alertDialog51.show();               
                }
            });     
        }
        else {          
        
        Intent intnt=new Intent(getBaseContext(), Tab.class);
        startActivity(intnt);           
                                        
        }
        return null; // don't interact with the ui! 
    } 
     
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)  
    {  
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) 
            { 
            this.dialog.dismiss(); 
            }
      } 
  }  
  }
```

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez : I didn't feel so...

Comment: Priyanka please edit your question, format code. It is difficult to read your code.

Comment: What system are you trying to login to?

Comment: I am trying to login using user name Priyanka and password Priyanka but is showing in correct user name and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Void > {
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Rig_ParkingActivity.this);@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
  this.dialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
  this.dialog.show();
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(final Void...unused) {
  Log.i("Priyanka", "username"
    username);
  Log.i("Priyanka", "password"
    password);
  String auth = BusinessLogic_login.candidatelogin(username, password);
  String userid = auth;
  Log.i("priyanka", "auth"
    auth);
  if (auth.equals("0") || (auth.equals(""))) {
    flag = true;
    Rig_ParkingActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        final AlertDialog alertDialog51;
        alertDialog51 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Rig_ParkingActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog51.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#00beb4'><b>Enter correct Email or Password</b></font>"));
        alertDialog51.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            alertDialog51.dismiss();
          }
        });
        alertDialog51.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            alertDialog51.dismiss();
          }
        });
        alertDialog51.show();
      }
    });
  }
  return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
  if (!flag) {
    Intent intnt = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Tab.class);
    startActivity(intnt);
  }
  if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
    this.dialog.dismiss();
  }
 }
}
```

try this code... Have a `boolean` value called **flag** and set it to false. I have just used it.. you have to initialize it.

`onPostExecute()` will run in the UI thread.. if you call intent in `doInBackground()` method it doesnt change in `UIThread` and you cant see the changes is what i got to know from your code.. check this

Comment: Could you explain what you did to the OP's code? What changed to make it work?

Comment: BobbeHoddi can put intent in to on post execute method and i think he  is correct